# AJAX error on Firefox extension(ported from Chrome)

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox-addon

I tried to convert a Chrome extenstion to Firefox using this tool http://www.extensionfactory.com/labs/conversion/ and it works great except the AJAX calls. Each time I make an AJAX call from the Firefox extension, I get this error(in Chrome works fine):

> [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://nfglncbjnghpllgmelioileejdnldcgm-api-utils-lib/securable-module.js
>   -> resource://nfglncbjnghpllgmelioileejdnldcgm-api-utils-lib/content/content-proxy.js
>   ::  :: line 97"  data: no]

This is the AJAX call in the content_script(chrome extension):

```js
var dataString='original_url='+imgsrc+'&filename='+filename+'&crop_x='+selX+'&crop_y='+selY+'&crop_h='+selH+'&crop_w='+selW;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.[website.com]/crop",
    data: dataString,
    async:false,
    success: function() {
        alert('Image successfully added!');

        iframe.src = iframe.src;

    } ,
    error:function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://[www.website.com]/loggedin",


            success: function() {
                alert('An error occured when uploading image to server! Please try again.');

            } ,
            error:function(){

                alert('You are not logged in! Please login.');
                window.open('http://[www.website.com]/login');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

I traced the error and nothing to be found, nothing related and I can't get more details from Firebug. I also verified the website address and server code and everything is fine, it just doesn't work on Firefox.

I'm thinking that Firefox Extension API has some limitations regarding to AJAX requests, but I don't know what to say since I couldn't find anything on the Internet.

Maybe you know what's happening here...

Comment: Why are you sending data with a GET request? While Firefox allows it, most servers don't.

Comment: Btw, it would have been important to mention that this is a content script - the conversion for the background page is a different one and XMLHttpRequest should work there.

Comment: AJAX request works ok, I got 500 error because it didn't send the cookie data which is required on the server because i'm working with sessions. The solution is to make it send cookie data like Chrome does.

Comment: Yea, that's the problem, Firefox doesn't pass session cookie with AJAX but chrome does. How can I make Firefox Extension to send session cookie as well?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to make a Firefox extension so it's difficult to give you a detailed answer, but I will say that the error message you are receiving is expected if you are trying to make network calls from within the extension sandbox environment because they don't allow it.

If you can, use their latest SDK which can be found here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/

You'll notice they have a class called "request" in their api that does exactly what you want.  It can be found here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html

One thing to note, if you use their latest SDK (1.4 at the time of this writing) it is not compatible with versions of Firefox prior to 4.

Comment: This conversion service is apparently creating add-ons using Add-on SDK 1.0 and one cannot change that. It is rather concerning that they mark add-ons as compatible with "Firefox 99" despite using this outdated SDK version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to upgrade it to latest sdk manually, because it seems it's buggy.